# How to put a normal command and a search command together in a vimscript?

Tags: search, command, vim

I'm trying without success to put a normal command together with a search command in a function using vimscript:

This is my command:
   `d/\S`
(delete from current cursor position to next "not space" character)

I don't know how to put this in vimscript.

I tried this but it doesn't work:
`normal d`
`let @/ = \\S`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
call search("\\S", "sW")
:normal d`'
```

The first line sets the ' previous context mark to the current cursor position, and then moves the cursor to the first non-whitespace char.

The second line then deletes backwards to the previous cursor position.